# Google App Engine dispatch.yaml Routing to Default Service Instead of Specified Service for /api/* URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm experiencing a routing issue with my Google App Engine (GAE) environment where requests to my /api/* endpoints are being served by the default service, despite having specified routing rules in my dispatch.yaml. I have a separate server service that should handle all API requests and a default service for my front-end.

Here's the relevant part of my dispatch.yaml:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: server
  - url: "*/*"
    service: default
```

And here is an example of my Express setup in the server service:

```
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import passport from './config/passport-config.js';
import apiRoutes from './routes/index-route.js';
import corsOptions from './config/cors-config.js';
import getEnvConfig from './config/env-config.js';
import { initializeDatabase } from './db/dao/index-dao.js';
const app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
console.log('por entrar a la ruta');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('ok');
});
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
const envConfig = await getEnvConfig();
const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    await initializeDatabase();
    const server = app.listen(envConfig.PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${server.address().port}`));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
startServer();
```

My server yaml is:

```
runtime: nodejs18
service: server
entrypoint: node src/app.js
```

and my client yaml is;

```
runtime: python39
service: default
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|json|ico|txt|map))
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|json|ico|txt|map)
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

When I navigate to https://server-dot-myprojectid.uc.r.appspot.com/, I expect to see 'Server is healthy', but instead, I'm served the front-end from the default service. The same happens when I try to access any /api/* endpoint; it's as if the default service captures all the traffic.

**I've confirmed that**:

The server service is deployed and can connect to the database successfully.
There are no errors in the GAE logs that indicate a problem with the server service.
I have redeployed dispatch.yaml after making changes to it.

**I expect** that any request to a path starting with /api/ should be routed to the server service, and all other requests should go to the default service.
ACTUAL RESULT:
Both the server service and the default service are serving the front-end, and the server service's API routes are not being hit.

Could anyone suggest what might be going wrong or what I should check next? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
The urls, are:
https://server-dot-appme-395223.uc.r.appspot.com/ => server
https://appme-395223.uc.r.appspot.com/ => default

Comment: I don't see where your ```server``` is returning - ```'Server is healthy'```. According to the code you posted, you just send ```ok```. Secondly, you have ```entrypoint: node src/app.js``` . Is your app organized such that it recognizes a folder structure of ```src``` which has a child file ```app.js```?